# How to catch HTTP errors in Javascript

Tags: javascript, streamdeck

I'm writing a Stream Deck plugin in Javascript and I want to log errors to a file.  I can't figure out how to capture details of network errors.  These errors appear in the debug console, but how can I get them in my own log?  The `xhr.onerror()` method returns not much useful info, just status code 0.
I tried adding a window error event listener, but that never triggers.  For example this code here:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.onerror = function() {console.log('xhr error', arguments)}
window.onerror = function() {console.log('window error', arguments)}
xhr.open('GET', 'http://badurl12345')
xhr.send()
```

Running this code in the debug console, I see `GET http://badurl12345/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`.  But I can't get this info from the error handler.

Comment: why don't use try catch ?

Comment: @dılosürücü - It doesn't work for what the OP is describing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that level of information is available to the JavaScript code. Even the much-newer `fetch` API severely restricts the information you get when a [network error occurs](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-network-error) (such as your name resolution failure example):

> A response whose type is "error" is known as a network error.
>
> A network error is a response whose status is always 0, status message is always the empty byte sequence, header list is always empty, and body is always null.